# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into users(name,email) values(mahmud,mahmudul@gamil.com))

Tags: laravel-5, mysql-workbench, homestead

I am using MySql Workbench for database. All doing well when I migrate my project.But when I want to insert data to the users table that time occurs this error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into users(name,email) values(mahmud,mahmudul@gamil.com))"

I am using windows, laravel 5.8,Homestead, MySql Workbench.

**here some file:**

.env:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7PN1.png)

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:KRf7nQxvFaheTWWPsflVa4KYZXR5Jwo5IvwXxogDJn4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

database.php:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nru8q.png)

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '33060'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ]
```

web.php:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pClYf.png)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/insert',function(){
    DB::insert("insert into users(name,email) values(?,?)",["mahmud","mahmudul@gamil.com"]);
});
```

page like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgyys.png)

**please help me how to solve it.**

thanks advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I added my some code to understand to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change .env and database.php:

**.env:**

replace

```
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
DB_HOST = localhost
```

**and**

**database.php:**

replace

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
```

to

```
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
```

**note:** MySql Connection Hostname will be 127.0.0.1 and port will be 33060:

Answer (score 0):

```
go to your config/database.php and paste below code
      'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```